# Why is my itemize line spacing so huge?

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize, line-spacing, flow-charts

My other itemize doesn't have this problem so why does this have it?
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0em}{\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Bài}

\makeatother



\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}



\begin{document}
\chapter{ Sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{text} = [textwidth = 3em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are using the `twoside` option. That forces `\flushbottom`, so latex tries to fill the page until the bottom. As you have a large picture and tabulars this means that latex has to stretch the space in the itemize. Either use `\raggedbottom` or let your picture and tabular float.

Comment: So how do i fix it? Delete the twoside option?

Comment: well depends what you want. Try it out and look what changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `[noitemsep]` argument.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{0em}{\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Bài}

\makeatother



\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}



\begin{document}
\chapter{ Sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{text} = [textwidth = 3em]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok so I want my list to be like the other so what should I put inside the []?

Comment: labelindent=25pt does that work inside it?

Answer (score 4):

With `twoside` printing, you get `\flushbottom`, that is, vertical spaces on pages are stretched so the final baseline is at the bottom of the text block.

In a document with big blocks like the present one, this will most likely cause the problem you see.

Use `\raggedbottom`.

I made also a few other changes.

1. I chose the combination `tgtermes` and `newtxmath` instead of `mathptmx`. The text font is TeX Gyre Termes, which is a clone of Times and in its Vietnamese version it has less slanted accents. The math font provided by `newtxmath` has much better rendering than `mathptmx`, which is a decades old hack.
2. `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for several years.
3. There's no reason for the `\DeclareRobustCommand` instructions you used.
4. You don't want to change `\@chapapp`, but `\chaptername`.
5. I removed `\arraybackslash` from the definition of the column types; this forces using `\tabularnewline` when the last column is `M` or `P` type, but avoids clumsy `\par` commands in the cells.
6. I added `\linespread{1.05}` to get a slightly wider distance between baselines, in order to avoid double accents clashing with descenders on the previous line.

Check also a couple of places marked with `<---` in the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%% array
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

%% enumitem
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: }% <--- a space here!
  {0em}
  {\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

%% tikz
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  line/.style = {
    draw,
    -latex',
  },
  text/.style = {textwidth = 3em}
}

%% personal commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\newcommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\newcommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author \\ \@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother

%% final settings
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Bài}}
\linespread{1.05}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn

\medskip % <--- space out a bit

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \tabularnewline
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \\ Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \tabularnewline
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \\ Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \tabularnewline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \tabularnewline
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \tabularnewline
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \tabularnewline
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \tabularnewline
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \tabularnewline
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, another way to cope with the problem is to add captions to the tables and pictures and to let them float with `table` and `figure` environments.